# how to populate table view cell or controller with rest api call using objective c

Tags: ios

https://github.com/svenanders/iOS7-Rest-Example-App

i tried out this coding...but it doesn't works for my url ...my data format like this...

```
{"wk_times":[{"user":{"id":1,"name":"Redmine Admin"},"hours":11.0,"startdate":"2015-07-27","status":"n"},{"user":{"id":1,"name":"Redmine Admin"},"hours":42.0,"startdate":"2015-07-20","status":"n"}
```

i have to show this data in a table view cell like:

> startdate | status | username

could anyone help me....regarding this...i am new to ios development

Comment: Format the data in the question so it is easily understandable. Also you need to provide your attempt at the code to get help, SO is not a service to write your code for you.

Comment: i used the above mentioned github coding....but it doesn't works...

Comment: Developing is not about google, copy code, paste code and ask why it does not work. It is about writing and understanding code and that takes study, practice and time. There are lot's of resources on the web to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

For now just to resolve your problem follow this. Better you can look at some `UITableView` tutorials and JSON parsing, and learn about `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`. This will perfectly help you to do things.

As per the source code. In completion handler block defined in fetchRestData after the JSON Serialisation. like follows:

```
NSDictionary *rest_data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
```

Create an NSArray on your ViewController interface as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *users;
```

As per your response JSON you have mentioned in the question, You need to get the users in an array like:

```
self.users = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[rest_data objectForKey:@"wk_times"]];
```

Now you have list of users to be displayed in your table view.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return self.users.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // Create cell to display the data.
     NSDictionary *userDict = self.users[indexPath.row];  // This userDict will have this {"user":{"id":1,"name":"Redmine Admin"},"hours":11.0,"startdate":"2015-07-27","status":"n"}
     NSDictionary *user = userDict[@"user"];   // This user will have {"id":1,"name":"Redmine Admin"}
     NSString *name = user[@"name"];
     NSString *userId = user[@"id"];
     // Using these data you set to the table cells.
}
```

This may help you.